# Probability of exactly $m$ out of $n$ dices of $2$ states turning into one state after $2$ throws.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

*Thanks to **aschepler** for pointing out a calculation error, which is now corrected.*

Suppose you have a special type of dice such that, instead of painted numbers on its faces, has only $2$ possible states: it's either $1$ or $0$. The probability of throwhing one of thoses dices and getting a $1$ is $p$, and therefore the probability of getting a $0$ is $(1-p)$.

Now, let's suppose that you will throw exacly $n$ of those dices on a box, open it, and remove all "$1$" dices. Then, throw the remaining dices on a box, open it, and again remove all "$1$" dices.

**What is the probability that the sum of the total "$1$" dices you removed on the first and second throw is exacly $m$?**

Of course, $m \leq n$ and $0 \leq p \leq 1$.

I've come into an "answer" by myself to this question, expanding the idea for only one throw, but I don't know wheter it breaks or not because of the fact that, for example, in the very first throw $m+1$ dices might be "$1$", inutilizing the second throw. Or, maybe, after the second throw the total sum might be bigger than $m$.

Here's how I did it:

$\text{Let } x = \text{The number of dices turned "1" after the first throw}$

$\text{Let } y = \text{The number of dices turned "1" after the second throw}$

$\text{We want } x + y = m$

$\text{The probability that exactly } x \text{ dices are turned "1" in the first throw is:}$

- $\binom{n}{x} \times p^x \times (1-p)^{n-x}$
- $\text{Where } \binom{n}{x} \text{ is the total ways one can choose exacly } x \text{ dices out of n}.$

$\text{The probability that exactly } y \text{ dices are turned "1" in the second throw is:}$

- $\binom{n-x}{y} \times p^y \times (1-p)^{n-x-y}$

$\text{Therefore the probability of these events happening consecutively is:}$

- $\binom{n}{x} \times \binom{n-x}{y} \times p^{x+y} \times (1-p)^{2n-2x-y}$

$\text{Since } y = m - x:$

- $P_{x} = \binom{n}{x} \times \binom{n-x}{m-x} \times p^{m} \times (1-p)^{2n-m-x}$

$\text{We need the total probability, which is the sum of all probabilities from every } 0 \leq x \leq m$

- $P = \sum\limits_{x=0}^{m}{\binom{n}{x} \times \binom{n-x}{m-x} \times p^{m} \times (1-p)^{2n-m-x}} = \dfrac{p^m \times n!}{(n-m)!} \times \sum\limits_{x=0}^{m}{\dfrac{(1-p)^{2n-m-x}}{(m-x)! x!}} $

$\text{Doing a little bit of algebra to transform the sum into a Newton's binomial, we get:}$

- $ P = \dfrac{p^m \times n! \times (1-p)^{2n} \times (\frac{1}{(1-p)^2} + \frac{1}{(1-p)})^m}{(n-m)! \times m!} = \dfrac{p^m \times n! \times (2-p)^m \times (1-p)^{2n-2m}}{m! \times (n-m)!} = \binom{n}{m} \times p^m \times (2-p)^m \times (1-p)^{2n-2m}$

That was my final answer, but I don't know wheter my logic is right for the reasons metioned above. Also, could there be a way to expand this even futher, to $3,4,5...k$ throws?

Thanks for your attention if you read all of this, and sorry for the uglyness of the post, it's due to inexperience.

Comment: Oh, my bad, the sum is actually from $x = 0$ to $m$. I'll edit, thanks.

Comment: If $m=0$ you have $P=n!$.

Comment: For future brevity, a two sided die is a coin.

Comment: Indeed, a coin is a better analogy! But I hope the dice one didn't hindered the understanding of the question.

Comment: Yes, for m = 0 it doesn't work, is my logic flawed or it's some kind of exepction on the suppositions I made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic seems good, but I think something has gone wrong in the calculations. Continuing from...

$$ P = \frac{p^m \cdot n!}{(n-m)!} \sum_{x=0}^m \frac{(1-p)^{2n-m-x}}{(m-x)!\, x!}$$

$$ \begin{align*}
P &= \frac{p^m (1-p)^{2n-m} n!}{m! (n-m)!} \sum_{x=0}^m \frac{m!}{(m-x)!\,x!} (1-p)^{-x} \\
P &= \frac{p^m (1-p)^{2n-m} n!}{m! (n-m)!} \sum_{x=0}^m {m \choose x} \left(\frac{1}{1-p}\right)^x \\
P &= \frac{p^m (1-p)^{2n-m} n!}{m! (n-m)!} \left(1 + \frac{1}{1-p}\right)^m \\
P &= {n \choose m} p^m (1-p)^{2n-2m} (2-p)^m
\end{align*}$$

This result even suggests another way to look at the problem: The possible matching results have cases for each of the ${n \choose m}$ ways we can choose $m$ of the $n$ dice which should eventually roll a 1. Each of these dice has probability $p$ of rolling 1 the first time, or $(1-p)p$ of rolling 1 the second time, for a total of $p+(1-p)p = 2p-p^2$. So the probability all $m$ of those dice do eventually roll a 1 is $(2p-p^2)^m$. The probability that each of the other $n-m$ dice roll 0 both times is $(1-p)^{2(n-m)}$. Multiplying the number of combinations and these two probability factors gives the result.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks a lot! That second way of seeing the problem is indeed quite elegant.

Comment: My calculation error was forgetting about the (1-p)^2n factor, lol.